# Jasper report use InputStream image multiple time

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to use some images multiple times in the footer of jasper report.

when using InputStream it is only represented once or doesn't render. The images dynamic come from data base it is represented in Java DTO object.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I set **Using Cache** property to true

[jasper studio snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x6ee.png)